# Azure Build Issues >> Publish Through VS 2022 Community Edition is causing 404 Errors at Many Action

Tags: azure, visual-studio, azure-appservice

**Problem:**
My .NET Core App, hosted on Azure App Services, is encountering 404 Exceptions for various UI actions.

**App Overview:**
It's an ASP.NET Core App hosted on Azure (PaaS/Azure App Services).

**Publishing Details:**
We're using VS 2022 Community Edition and performing a manual publish.

**Local Testing:**
Everything works smoothly during local testing.

**Temporary Fix:**
The problem is sometimes resolved by publishing again or restarting the App Services.

**Seeking Help:**
Any insights into what might be causing this issue? Could there be any missing configurations either in Azure or Microsoft?

Thanks!

Ashish Tripathi

Comment: Can you please share your code ?What is the version of your App?

Comment: Please share your `.csproj` and `Program.cs` file.

Comment: `404 Exceptions for various UI actions`, what is that UI action you are trying?

Answer (score 0):

> encountering 404 Exceptions for various UI actions.

- 404 exception usually occurs if the App does not find the resource which you have requested.
- As you have mentioned the app is working locally, then the Azure App service might be idle for long time.

[image]

- Enable the `Always on` option in `Configuration` => `General settings` section.

[image]

- As mentioned in the MSDoc

> When **Always On** isn't turned on (default), the app is unloaded after 20 minutes without any incoming requests. The unloaded app can cause high latency for new requests because of its warm-up time. When **Always On** is turned on, the front-end load balancer sends a GET request to the application root every five minutes.

- Make sure your code is deployed to Azure App service correctly to the root folder of the application.
- To know more about the error in detail, change the `stdoutLogEnabled` value to true in `Web.config` file (which is in `site/wwwroot` folder) and run the app.
- `.log` file with the exception details will be generated in `\home\LogFiles` folder.